# What is the best way to take screenshots of a Window with C++ in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, screenshot

What is the best (easiest) way to take a screenshot of an running application with C++ under Windows?

Comment: This really helped: http://groups.google.com/group/win32-programming/browse_thread/thread/55c030edbaeaf026

Comment: How was this question off-topic?  It's asking how to do it programmatically, which seems pretty relevant to me (and isn't too uncommon).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You have to get the device context of the window ([`GetWindowDC()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144947(VS.85).aspx)) and copy image ([`BitBlt()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183370(VS.85).aspx)) from it. Depending on what else you know about the application you will use different methods to find which window's handle to pass into `GetWindowDC()`.

Comment: please add more details about how to use GetWindowDC and BitBlt to get screenshot. i want the details also....

Answer (score 13):

`GetDC(NULL)` + `BitBlt()`

To capture translucent/alpha/layered windows, you must pass the `CAPTUREBLT` flag to `BitBlt`, if you do that, the cursor blinks, read [this technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.02.windowsconfidential.aspx) to find out why.

On NT6+, you might be able to use the [Magnification API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms692402(VS.85).aspx) to do what you want.

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for that.
Now I remember, the one attempt I did which was causing the mouse pointer to blink was GetDC()+BitBlt(). Thats the main problem :( I don't want the pointer to blink... 

Any ways to get the screen shots seemlessly???

Comment: Just don't pass the CAPTUREBLT flag

Answer (score 3):

On the [keybd_event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646304(VS.85).aspx) function documentation it states that you can use it to take a screenshot and save it to the clipboard. For example:

```
keybd_event(VK_SNAPSHOT, 0, KEYEVENTF_SILENT, 0);
```

In my version (Visual Studio 2005 help installed on my computer) it states that you can take a screenshot of the whole desktop by setting the second parameter to 0, or a screen shot of just the current application by setting it to 1.

Taking it out of the clipboard buffer is left as an exercise for the reader.

However I'd think carefully before doing this as it will turf whatever image data was already present in the clipboard.

Comment: that's the event for the PrintScr key on the keyboard. the 'keybd_event' you stated cannot be used to take screenshot. what a concept mis-understanding!

Comment: @Paul Follow the link I've included and check out the Remarks section. It states: "An application can simulate a press of the PRINTSCRN key in order to obtain a screen snapshot and save it to the clipboard. To do this, call keybd_event with the bVk parameter set to VK_SNAPSHOT."

Comment: oh ok i see, didn't know we could simulate the press of printscr key :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example [code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183402(v=vs.85).aspx)
You can do `CaptureAnImage(GetDesktopWindow());` to make a screen capture.